# Async-http often hangs.

Tags: android, android-async-http, loopj

I start a ProgressDialog when I start my async request and on seemingly random occasions the dialogue does not dismiss (code does not fire onSuccess or onFailure). I handle both possible success responses from the server (one of which is an error) and I have a failure block so in theory the ProgressDialog should always dismiss. Can someone tell what event I am missing? Or is there a better structure?

My code structure:

1. I have a Gateway class that handles all the networking
2. The calling calls handles the .show() and .dismiss() events for the dialog

Gateway:

```
public static void post(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {
    client.post(getAbsoluteUrl(url), params, responseHandler);
}

public static void loadItems(final ItemAdapter itemAdapter, int itemID) {

    final String url = String.format(Constants.URL_ITEMS, itemID);

    post(url, null, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(JSONObject response) {

            try {
                if (!response.isNull("items")) {

                    itemAdapter.updateData(items);

                } else if (!response.isNull("error")) {

                   itemAdapter.signalError(response.getString("error"));

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                itemAdapter.signalError("An unknown error has occurred");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error)
        {
            if (error instanceof SocketTimeoutException || error instanceof ConnectTimeoutException) {
                itemAdapter.signalError("Connection timeout! Please check that you are connected to the internet");
            } else {
                itemAdapter.signalError("An unknown error has occurred");
            }
        }

    });

}
```

The adapter:

```
public ItemAdapter(Context context, int itemID) {

    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Items",
            "Loading items", true);
    Gateway.loadItems(this, itemID);


}

public void updateData(ArrayList<Items> items) {
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    this.items = items;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void signalError(String errorMessage) {

    progressDialog.dismiss();

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle("Error")
            .setMessage(errorMessage)
            .setNegativeButton("OK", null).show();

}
```

Comment: add a log message which reports to you everytime onFailure is called.

Comment: I did. There are occasions where neither failure or success is called.

Comment: buddy please add your Gateway Class too..

Comment: The first bit of code it the relevant part of the Gateway class. It hosts all of the server requests so it's fairly long.

Comment: what http library are you using?

Comment: I was using: http://loopj.com/android-async-http/ but i gave up on it. That said is you have a good answer it can be useful for others.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea what your code is doing, but your if statements look suspicious.

```
if (!response.isNull("items")) {
  itemAdapter.updateData(items);
} else if (!response.isNull("error")) {
 itemAdapter.signalError(response.getString("error"));
}
```

could it be that none of the two conditions are met? If so, the dialog will not be dismissed. You only dismiss it on exception or if one of the above conditions are met.

Comment: It's looking for the keys "items" or "error" in the JSON. These are the only two options.

Comment: Those may be the only two valid options but if your server is failing in some unexpected way then the response may contain something other than those two values.

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere that there is a design flaw in the library and people had some problems with the same issue.

But the most reliable solution was to override all the `onSuccess` and `onFailure` methods in the `JsonHttpResponseHandler`. In that way you can be sure that a communication is going on.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes I do that for everyone of my posts. And I add logging in each to check if they are being called. The problem is that on random instances neither is called.

Comment: In your code you do not override all the `onSuccess` and all the `onFailure` methods. There are more then one of each. http://loopj.com/android-async-http/doc/com/loopj/android/http/JsonHttpResponseHandler.html

Comment: That makes sense. I will investigate.

Comment: Two days of testing. In 18% of cases (wrote a loop to send thousands of request) it hits none of the successes and failures. This is driving me crazy. I think I will change frameworks.

Comment: Oh :/ That is really bad news. I hope you will find a better framework. I normally always use the android.os.AsyncTask and the org.apache.http classes from the Android API to retrieve the json from my server. I never had any problems using them.

Comment: BTW .. a while ago I had a problem with my code that was requesting a json string from server. In some occasions I would never get a response. I finally decided to change the server and now everything works fine.

Comment: Yes maybe I should have done that.  I come from the world of iOS (same server and same API) and everything is a framework that's why I looked for one.

Comment: I understand :) Well if you want to create your own class for downloading json and to parse it there is a bunch of tutorials how to do it and it is really easy.

Comment: If you are looking for really good library use Retrofit http://square.github.io/retrofit/ It's written by one of the Android's brainiac Jake Wharton.

Answer (score 0):

Handle else case also onSuccess method like

@Override
        public void onSuccess(JSONObject response) {

```
        try {
            if (!response.isNull("items")) {

                itemAdapter.updateData(items);

            } else if (!response.isNull("error")) {

               itemAdapter.signalError(response.getString("error"));

            } else {
               // Code to dismiss the dialog
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            itemAdapter.signalError("An unknown error has occurred");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

Comment: The whole method does not fire. It's not a problem with the if/then block.

Answer (score -1):

If your main concern is just closing ProgressDialog .. then try like this .

```
try{

 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                                   progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                   });

}catch(Exception beauty)
{
// Log error if any .. 
}
```

Hope it helps!